# use openmp in iterating over a map

Tags: c++

I'm trying to iterate over a map in c++ using openMP, but I got three error messages saying
that the  initialization, termination and increment of my loop has improper form and I'm quite   new in using openmp, so is there any way to get around this problem while getting the same  results as the serial ones? the following is the code I used

```
map< int,string >::iterator datIt;
#pragma omp parallel for
for(datIt=dat.begin();datIt!=dat.end();datIt++) //construct the distance matrix
{
...............
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely your implementation of OpenMP is incompatible with STL iterators.  While there have been some [changes to the standard to make OMP more compatible with the STL](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/11/09/openmp-30-and-iterators/), I think you'll find your implementation doesn't support such behaviour. Most OpenMP implementations I've encountered are at most version 2.5, Microsoft C++ is 2.0. The only compiler I'm aware of that supports 3.0 is the Intel C++ compiler.

A few other points, you should use std::begin, and std::end. Also, you either need to declare your loop invariant as private, or have OpenMP figure that out by itself, like so:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(map< int,string >::iterator datIt = std::begin(dat);
    datIt != std::end(dat);
    datIt++)
{
     //construct the distance matrix...
}
```

But without 3.0 support, this is beside the point.

Comment: gcc supports OpenMP 3.0 since version 4.4 and will have support for 3.1 in version 4.7, so it's mostly visual c++ which is stuck in the stone age. Besides even with openmp 3.0 only `random_access_iterators` are allowed as loop variable, but `map` only supports `bidrectional_iterators`, so that doesn't help. And why should `std::begin`, `std::end` be preferred over the member functions, I don't see any benefit from that, since it does nothing but call the memberfunction anyways.

Comment: @Grizzly I wasn't aware of the GCC OpenMP support, thanks for that. And you should use the non-member begin(...) and end(...) because they can be specialised to support containers that lack a begin and end member function. This places the emphasis on generic programming, which is what good C++ is all about. And if you won't take my word for it, take [Herb Sutter's](http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/).

Comment: Considering the type of the iterator is explicitly mentioned in the code that doesn't make it any more generic. Besides `std::begin` generally can't be specialized for containers which lack the member functions, since you can't partially specialize function templates and adding overloads in `std` is not allowed. To make it more generic you would need to use an unqualified version (`begin()`, `end()`) coupled with `using namespace std;` or `using std::begin; using std::end;`, since I would assume that containers are more likely to have the memberfunctions then a freestanding namespace version

Comment: Besides isn't the freestanding version only availible since C++11, so not an option yet for a lot of programmers? I'm not really disagreeing with the principle of using free functions for a more generic interface, but your answer doesn't provide any additional genericity, making your advice kind of pointless

Comment: @Grizzly First of all, I didn't give this advice solely in the context of the example, and you should be both consistent and adhere to best practices. Second, specialising std::begin or std::end doesn't require partial specialisation. Third, you're not supposed to overload standard library functions, you are however permitted to specialise them. Fourth, const char* does have .begin/end(), there's one of many examples. Finally, VS2010 supports std::begin/end(), as does GCC 4.6 onwards: that aside, they're a pair of 4 line functions, totalling a trivial 8 line change to the standard library.

Comment: A lot of containers are template classes. Therefore you can't specialize `std::begin()` and `std::end()` for those, since you can't partial specialize function templates. Therefore you would need overloading, which is illegal for standard library functions. Thus if you want to be truely generic you need to call it unqualified. For your forth point: `const char*` doesn't have `begin()` and `end()` either, you mean `const char[]`. And that is just about the only example I can think of when using C++11. And  you can't really assume the code needs to work on newest compilers only.

Comment: @Grizzly This functionality wasn't added to absolutely cope with template classes, although it does to a large extent. It was added to unify non-template mechanisms and external libraries with the STL, making the language more consistent. Const char* and const char[] are the same thing, and I can think of hundreds of other examples, C libraries which require onerous abstraction to be used intuitively in C++. And of course I can assume the asker wants to write modern C++, the only reason not to use C++11 is when working on legacy systems, and anyone doing so should know their limits.

Comment: For some up-to-date information, you have a detailed list on the OpenMP website:
https://www.openmp.org/resources/openmp-compilers-tools/

Answer (score 8):

It could be done also by using a simple index based for loop clubbed with `std::advance` to reach to a particular map element. OpenMP 2.0 supports index based for loops very well.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i < dat.size(); i++) {
        auto datIt = dat.begin();
        advance(datIt, i);
        //construct the distance matrix using iterator datIt
    }
```

In each thread the iterator `datIt` will point to a map item and can be used to perform operations on it.

Answer (score 1):

OpenMP 3.0 available now on gcc and Intel compiler has *task* directive that allow a thread to delegate task to a pool of thread

Inspired from : [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433048/c-openmp-and-non-random-access-stl-containers-a-possible-workaround) and [this course](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~mhall/cs4961f11/CS4961-L9.pdf), I wrote these kind of code that work fine for me :

```
map< int,string >::iterator datIt;
...
#pragma omp parallel for
#pragma omp single nowait
 {
  for(datIt=dat.begin();datIt!=dat.end();datIt++) //construct the distance matrix
  {
   #pragma omp task firstprivate(datIt)
   {
    ...............
   } 
  }
 }
```

One task (*single* directive) loop over the whole map and put every task to do for every element in map into a pool of tasks. Other OMP threads process tasks remains in this pool. There is not necessary for others OMP task to wait the end of *for* loop to start task processing (*nowait*). Every task has a pointer of element in map to process (*firstprivate(datIt)*).

Constraint : Every task must be independent and map mustn't change before the end.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way if its helpful.

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(dat) private(datIt) 
for(map< int,string >::iterator datIt=dat.begin();datIt!=dat.end();datIt++) 
{
 ...............
}
```