# c++: OpenMP and non-random-access STL containers - a possible workaround

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, parallel-processing, openmp

So on SO, and the Internets in general, there is much confusion and frustration about how to make OpenMP's easy-to-use `#pragma` directives  cooperate  with C++'s equally easy-to-use STL containers.

Everyone talks about work-arounds for STL `vector`, but what about non-random access / bi-directional containers, like `map`, `list`, `set`, etc. ?

I encountered this problem and devised a very simple, obvious workaround.  I present it here for STL `map`, but it is clearly generalizable.

Serial version:

```
for (std::map<A,B>::iterator it = my_map.begin();
        it != my_map.end();
        ++it)       
    { /* do work with  it   */  }
```

My proposed solution to use OpenMP with STL `map`:

```
    //make an array of iterators.
    int loop_length = my_map.size();
    std::map<A,B>::iterator loop_array[ loop_length ];

    std::map<A,B>::iterator allocate_it = my_map.begin();
    for (int j=0; j<loop_length; ++j)
        loop_array[j] = allocate_it++;

    // now you can use OpenMP as usual:
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (uint j=0; j<loop_length; ++j) 
       { /* do work with    loop_array[j]    */  }
```

I am far from an expert on OpenMP, however, so **I would like to know if my proposed work-around is efficient and good practice.**

Please assume that the programmer is responsible for thread-safe handling of the STL container within the for loop.

Finally, is my proposed solution more efficient than the following commonly-proposed solution [(see answer to this SO Question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513988/iteration-through-std-containers-in-openmp), because, in my solution,each thread does not iterate over the whole container?

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    for (std::map<A,B>::iterator it = my_map.begin();
            it != my_map.end();
            ++it) 
    #pragma single nowait
       {   /*  do work  */   }

}
```

Comment: I would suspect this to be faster (at least when `A` and `B` are large, otherwise you could just copy them into a `vector`). But have you tried it on your problem? Was it faster?

Comment: @larsmans I have not done any performance tests, and don't really plan too (sorry).   I already have a large, sophisticated program written in serial, with STL containers everywhere, and am trying to multithread certain STL-for-loops.  As such, I can't easily isolate and time it...

Comment: Not even if you copy the contents of the containers to a `vector` for testing purposes?

Comment: Sorry if my question is stupid but could you not simply iterate over `j` and then access the elements via `allocate_it+j` where allocate it is set as in your post.

Comment: @Azrael3000  But isn't iterator arithmetic only valid for random-access iterators (like for `vector`) ?  `map` , `list`, `set`, only use bi-directional iterators.

Answer (score 5):

OpenMP provides the `task` construct starting with version 3.0 which is quite useful for use with STL:

```
for (std::map<A,B>::iterator it = my_map.begin();
        it != my_map.end();
        ++it)       
{
   #pragma omp task
   { /* do work with  it   */  }
}
```

Of course, data dependencies between iterations should not exist for this to work.

Comment: Is there extra overhead due to have the OpenMP command inside the loop?  In general, I thought that performance is best improved by parallelizing the largest section of code possible (e.g. the outermost loop in nested loops).

Comment: That's generally true but using `omp for` on the for loop requires fast random access iterators (e.g. that run in constant time). As far as I know std::map does not provide a random access iterator at all and you should simulate one.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to do in my "proposed solution", by creating the conventional (random-access) array and then looping for that instead of the map directly.  I was just concerned that your method created too much overhead (thread management at every iteration).

Comment: OpenMP does not create separate thread for each task. On the contrary, tasks are put in a "bag" and then each thread steals a task. My colleagues' research shows that the overhead is almost negligible while coding is greatly simplified. I am not trying to persuade you to use tasks - just try and see which one is faster and which one requires more programming.