# OpenMP: how to realize thread local object in task?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

What I am trying to do is to iterate over all elements of a container in parallel comparable to `#pragma omp for`; however the container in question does not offer a random access iterator. I therefore use a workaround via tasks described in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10456684/11554022):

```
for (std::map<A,B>::iterator it = my_map.begin();
        it != my_map.end();
        ++it)       
{
   #pragma omp task
   { /* do work with  it   */  }
}
```

My problem is that a 'scratch space' object is needed in each iteration; this object is expensive to construct or copy into the data environment of the task. It would only be necessary to have a single **thread local object for each thread; in the sense that each task uses the object of the thread it is executed on**. `private` requires a copy and `shared` results in a race condition. **Is there a way to realize this with OpenMP?**

I researched `#pragma omp threadprivate`, however the objects are not static, as the structure of the program looks something like this:

```
method(int argument_for_scratch_object){
   #pragma omp parallel
   {
      Object scratch(argument_for_scratch_object);

      //some computations are done here...
   
      #pragma omp single nowait
      {
         //here goes the for loop creating the tasks above
         //each task uses the scratch space object
      }
   }
}
```

If `scratch` was declared static (and then made `threadprivate`) before the parallel region, it would be initialized with argument_for_scratch_object of the first method call; which might not be correct for the subsequent method calls.

Comment: `#pragma omp threadprivate` is really what you are looking for. As for _"objects are not static"_ — Why? Then, make them static.

Comment: I believe `threadprivate` variables must be either global (file scope) or static in block scope or static class members. A non-static `threadprivate` block-scope variable doesn't make too much sense to me. Remember that `threadprivate` is a property of a variable at its definition, not a data sharing attribute when opening a parallel scope. For a full answer, please describe you use / manage *scratch space* objects and why static or global are not an option.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @DanielLangr and @Zulan! As clarification: all of this happens in a method, the scratch space object constructor needs an argument of the method. If I make the scratch space object static, it might not be correct in subsequent calls of the method. (I hope I understand correctly, apologies if this is a beginner misconception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your update, I would suggest to use a global/static thread-private pointer and then initialize it by each thread within your parallel section.

```
static Object* scratch_ptr;
#pragma omp threadprivate(scratch_ptr);

void method(int argument_for_scratch_object)
{
#pragma omp parallel
  {
    scratch_ptr = new Object(argument_for_scratch_object);
    ...
    delete scratch_ptr;  
  }
}
```