# OpenMP Parallelizing for loop with map

Tags: c++, openmp, stdmap, icc

I am trying to parallelize a for-loop which scans std::map. Below is my toy program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <omp.h>

#define NUM 100000

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  omp_set_num_threads(16);
  int realThreads = 0;
  string arr[] = {"0", "1", "2"};
  std::map<int, string> myMap;
  for(int i=0; i<NUM; ++i)
    myMap[i] = arr[i % 3];

  string is[NUM];

  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(map<int, string>::iterator it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); it++)
  {
    is[it->first] = it->second;
    if(omp_get_thread_num() == 0)
      realThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
  }
  printf("First for-loop with %d threads\n", realThreads);

  realThreads = 0;
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i=0; i<NUM; ++i)
  {
    assert(is[i] == arr[i % 3]);
    if(omp_get_thread_num() == 0)
      realThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
  }
  printf("Second for-loop with %d threads\n", realThreads);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation command:

```
icc -fopenmp foo.cpp
```

The output of the above code block is:

```
First for-loop with 1 threads
Second for-loop with 16 threads
```

Why am I not able to parallelize the first for-loop?

Comment: How are you determining whether you have successfully parallelized?

Comment: i don't think `std::map` is thread-safe and can't think a way how it can be looped concurrently without convert it to array first

Comment: @merlin2011 - The output comes from omp_get_num_threads() which is inside the for-blocks.

Comment: @BryanChen - I got the idea from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848870/use-openmp-in-iterating-over-a-map)

Comment: @BryanChen, as long as the OP is not changing the map (e.g. adding or deleting entries) in his loop and is over iterating over it then it's thread-safe.

Comment: The flag to enable OpenMP in icc is "-openmp", not "-fopenmp", so there's something wrong here. You are probably not enabling OpenMP at all (except that your claimed output should only be possible if you are...)

Comment: @JimCownie, as documented in the ICC manual, `-fopenmp` is an alternate option to enable OpenMP support on Linux and OS X.

Comment: @HristoIliev Ah, you're right! I had never noticed that before. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`std::map` does not provide random-access iterators, only the usual bi-directional iterator. OpenMP requires that the iterators in parallel loops are of random-access type. With other kind of iterators explicit tasks should be used instead:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
  #pragma omp master
  realThreads = omp_get_num_threads();

  #pragma omp single
  for(map<int, string>::iterator it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); it++)
  {
    #pragma omp task
    is[it->first] = it->second;
  }
}
```

Note in that case a separate task is created for each member of the map. Since the task body is very computationally simple, the OpenMP overhead will be relatively high in that particular case.